# Tuple-based windows in Apache Beam

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-flink, apache-beam

How does one create tuple-based sliding windows in Apache Beam? This is very easy to do in Flink:

```
DataStream.countWindowAll(long size, long slide)
```

But it is unclear from the docs for Beam (or DataFlow) how to do this. Is it some combination of windows and triggers? Is it efficient?

Answer (score 0):

Sliding windows are natively supported in Beam. Please see the [programming guide](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#windowing) and documentation for the [SlidingWindows](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/0.6.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/windowing/SlidingWindows.html) class.

E.g.:

```
PCollection<Foo> foos = ...;
PCollection<Integer> counts = foos
    .apply(Window.into(
        SlidingWindows.of(Duration.standardMinutes(5))
                      .every(Duration.standardMinutes(1))))
    // Below is required instead of Count.globally() when you use
    // a non-global windowing function.
    .apply(Combine.globally(Count.<Foo>combineFn()).withoutDefaults());
PCollection<String> formattedCounts = counts.apply(
        ParDo.of(new DoFn<Integer, String>() {
          @ProcessElement
          public void process(ProcessContext c, BoundedWindow w) {
            c.output("Window: " + w + ", count: " + c.element());
          }
        }));
```

Triggering is a separate dimension of the problem, and it controls when the data for a particular window will be considered "complete enough" to apply the aggregation. See [programming guide](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#triggers).